# Why is my Minecraft world spawning me in the air?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I've been playing in this PE world for a while now, and this has happened multiple times. I join the world and I am spawned in the air right above the spawn point and proceed to fall to my death, is there some in-game reason for this? Am I saving the game wrong?

Comment: What's in the area, just regular terrain? Did you set your spawn point with a command?

Comment: yeah regular terrain, and i didn't set a command @FabianRöling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## This is a 1.8 Bug.

I found a forum on this, it seems to be quite common.

> Until 1.9 is released, the death effects of the bug can be remedied by using slime blocks at spawn or by using a totem of undying. Obviously the former is cheaper and more desirable, but if you plan a trek to the End, always save and quit with a totem equipped.
> <sub><sup>*- [Spawning in midair - Mojang Bugs](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-38374)*</sup></sub>

So it seems like this is a Bug that wont be resolved until whenever 1.9 is released. So the only available solution (at the moment) is make something to break your fall.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you create a Minecraft world, it creates a new terrain and a new **spawn point.** This 'spawning in the air' could be because the spawn point system has been corrupted, because there used to be terrain in that position, or because the system thought there was terrain there, e.g. vines...

Comment: I have been into that world, and there was no terrain in that place