# Logging into Minecraft equals instant death for no reason?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My girlfriend and I play Minecraft often and recently with the 1.8.0 update (Pocket Edition), she has randomly logged into her world to tell me that she randomly died as soon as she joins. This is her own locally created world.

We then created a Realm about 2 days ago, for this reason, hoping it wouldn't happen there. However, I remember last time I played, I was in the safety of my home, not near lava or monsters, inside my well-lit house. When suddenly, literally as soon as the world loads, I get a screen that says, “You have died”. I looked around my whole house to see if I could find any of my stuff, but it all disappeared. Why is this happening? It’s not an isolated issue with just Realm servers. This has happened on locally saved worlds as well.

Comment: 1. I changed the tag, because I assume you mean pocket edition, since you said "recent 1.8.0 update". Regular 1.8 was years ago. 2. Can you please shorten your question to a proper question instead of telling a story?

Comment: Did you do any AFK before you logged out last time, or get kicked?

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes, I meant the pocket edition. And I mentioned the story in case anyone wants to argue this was a one-time occurrence or a created world problem. I wouldn't write it out if I didn't feel like it had meaning. But thank you.

Comment: @Ben No, I was just playing regularly and decided to log out. I decided to log out in a location where I know dying would have been impossible.

Comment: Possibly the same as this answer? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/344044/93625  in that post, it states there's a bug with PE 1.8.0 causing death from falling, won't be fixed until 1.9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Minecraft world spawning me in the air?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344044/why-is-my-minecraft-world-spawning-me-in-the-air)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. A quick google search came up with the bug tracker, which includes work-arounds that I wouldn't have thought of.

https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-38374